# Can Google+ Friends See Your App Downloads on Play Store, or Just the Ones You Rated?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, privacy, google-plus

Can Google+ friends see all your app downloads on Play Store, or just the ones you rated?

Answer (score 1):

[Recent shared activity on Play](https://play.google.com/store/people/details?id=106189723444098348646) shows items you have [rated or +1'd](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4346705). Just installing an app, buying a book, or renting a video does not make the action listed.